# Reputation in the user profile is not vertically aligned

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, user-profiles

The numbers that show the reputation in [my profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/17121/n-n) are not vertically aligned. See the following screenshot:

[image: The reputation in my profile]

Also see the following zoomed screenshot which shows that `3` is one pixel taller than the other numbers:

[image: Clarification of the reputation in my profile]

Is this a bug in the font or in the site design? I am using Firefox 19.0 in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Looks fine to me, Opera 12.14 on Windows 7.

Comment: Also fine for me on Firefox ESR 17.0.3 and IE8 on Windows 7. Probably an issue with the font on Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks fine on chrome beta for android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this, which makes me think it's a local font issue like [John C](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16377/john-c) mentioned.

Not much I can do about that.